# BIG data in redux store

Tags: json, reactjs, redux

Well, let's get straight to the point. Thing is that I am getting bunch of data from API in JSON format(~1.5MB could be even more) and I should store that data in redux store. And show that data in kind of table/list.

To be more accurate I am getting something like this:

```
{
    id: 1,
    name: "John",
    surname: "Snow",
    hobby: "to know nothing"
}...
```

and I should show such data in editable table, something like this:

```
id|name|surname|hobby
1 |John|Snow   |to know nothing
```

So, my question is what would be the best way of storing and displaying such amount of data in redux store? Important thing to notice is that API has no pagination option, I am getting all the data in one chunk.

And now I am storing data in store like this:

```
{
    usersById: {
       1: {
           id: 1,
           name: "John",
           surname: "Snow",
           hobby: "to know nothing"
       }...
    }
}
```

and I believe that's fine. But my biggest concern that page is lagging or even freeze for a while once I get data from API, put it in store and display it in simple divs all at once. And I am not sure if that's OK as there is no possibility to get that data from API in chunks? Or am I doing something wrong? Because I am not doing any magic with that data, just simple get->put to store->display data in simple divs.

Any comments would be very appreciated.

Thanks :)

Comment: My opinion is that your data structure looks fine, because it is suited for loops and lookups of individual records. The inability to paginate API data could be problematic for you if page weight starts to cause lag. One option could be cache the external API in a system that does offer pagination. A good rule of thumb is to only request and or put in the store what you need for immediate use

Comment: I doubt that you need to render all the items all at once, so you probably should use some kind of pagination to limit the number of elements rendered at any given point. If the API always returns everything, then you will need to do pagination on the client, but plenty of solutions exist for that.

Comment: thanks for answers. So if I understand correctly, best option for my case would be just put everything in store as I do now, but read data from store in chunks? Is that correct?

Comment: That's more or less what I was saying, the point is that you probably don't ever need to render all the data, but I wouldn't assume that it's a problem to store it all on the client.

Comment: well, actually my example was a bit simplified. real example would be to have kind of excel table in page, and that means, that quite a lot will be displayed at once in that app I am making. 80-100cols(with scrollbar of course) and 30-50rows is quite standard. :)

Comment: Just search for something like "react scrollable table" and you will find plenty of useful stuff.

Answer (score 4):

Storing the data in your Redux store will probably do fine unless you're doing some heavy computation after downloading the data. But you may notice some of the problems you described when rendering the table.

One solution would be to window the results, i.e. all data is loaded in the Redux store, but you don't display everything at once.. instead you render the first 25/50/100 and only render more when you get to the bottom of the table (and can unmount the first ones that are not visible anymore).

A popular library to achieve this is [react-virtualized](https://github.com/bvaughn/react-virtualized), it makes really easy to implement this kind of logic of only rendering what is actually visible on the screen.

Comment: thanks for comment. it's actually very useful. but thing is I cannot use any external solution in my project. 
anyway, I am already checking react-virtualized and trying to understand how it works and which part exactly responsible for that "render-only-what-you-see". so far it's a bit confusing, but I believe I will find parts which I could use for my project. :)